# Google Cloud Datastore: Are its App Engine Libraries usable on Compute Engine?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I built a complex set of NDB models using ndb.Model and ndb.PolyModel with lots of StructuredProperty and specialized ndb.Property attributes for my Python App Engine app.

Is it possible to use the google.ext.ndb etc.. libraries that work on App Engine also on a Compute Engine instance?

This way I could use the same, comfortable NDB object model on both App Engine and Compute Engine for storing and querying data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NDB does not currently support Google Cloud Datastore (the API you can call from Compute Engine), but we are working on adding it. We don't have a timeline to share at this time, but you can receive notifications about the feature by subscribing this this issue on our GitHub tracker:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/2

Comment: Great. Looking forward to that. I have subscribed to the issue you mentioned.